# flutter: After Sql request open FIRST Item from List

Tags: sql, flutter, dart

So I am scanning a Barcode or I'm Introducing it manually and When I press Button to execute I get Full list of Items (Cards), when I press on them (one of Cards) -> I go to another page and It shows me more information about that Item.

But I would like to get automatically first Item opened when I press button, is there a way to do that?

Bellow I will share some screens and code in order to better understand what I try to say:

[image]

I would like to get First Item Opened Automatically After Request in First Screen (1 to 3)

And here is code:

```js
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sql_app/dita_conveer.dart';
import 'package:sql_app/info_produs.dart';
import 'package:sql_conn/sql_conn.dart';
import 'info_produs.dart';

class ditaStatie extends StatefulWidget {
  final String nrStatie;
  const ditaStatie({Key? key, required this.nrStatie}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ditaStatie> createState() => _ditaStatieState();
}

class _ditaStatieState extends State<ditaStatie> {
  final _scanCutieController = TextEditingController();
  bool vizibil = true;
  String cutieScan = '';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scanCutieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<List?> read(String query) async {
    final result = await SqlConn.readData(query);
    List _list = jsonDecode(result) as List;
    return _list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Visibility(
              visible: vizibil,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 6,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _scanCutieController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              width: 3,
                            )),
                        hintText: 'Scaneaza BarCode',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  // Butonul de Executarea selectiei
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Test'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            vizibil = !vizibil;
                          });
                          cutieScan = _scanCutieController.text;
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: !vizibil,
            child: Row(
              children: const [
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text('Adresa')),
                Expanded(flex: 5, child: Text('Denumirea Produs')),
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text('Comandat')),
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text('Scanat')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<List?>(
                future: read(
                    "SELECT ProductAdress, ProductName, NeedCount, ScanCount, ProductAdress, ProductBarCode, ProductSeriesCount, ProductExpirationDate FROM ScanRest WHERE ProductStation = '${widget.nrStatie}' AND BoxID = '${cutieScan}' ORDER BY ProductName ASC;"),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return const Text('Loading....');
                    default:
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        print("call error");
                        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      } else {
                        print("call success = ${snapshot.data}");
                        List data = snapshot.data ?? [];
                        return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Card(
                                elevation: 2,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => InfoProdus(
                                            denumProdus: (data[index]
                                                    as Map)['ProductName']
                                                .toString(),
                                            adresaProdus: (data[index]
                                                    as Map)['ProductAdress']
                                                .toString(),
                                            needCount: (data[index]
                                                    as Map)['NeedCount']
                                                .toString(),
                                            scanCount: (data[index]
                                                    as Map)['ScanCount']
                                                .toString(),
                                            dataExpirare: (data[index] as Map)[
                                                    'ProductExpirationDate']
                                                .toString(),
                                            productBarCode: (data[index]
                                                    as Map)['ProductBarCode']
                                                .toString(),
                                            productSeriesCount:
                                                (data[index] as Map)[
                                                        'ProductSeriesCount']
                                                    .toString(),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Row(children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Text(
                                          (data[index] as Map)['ProductAdress']
                                              .toString()),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 5,
                                      child: Text(
                                          (data[index] as Map)['ProductName']
                                              .toString()),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                            (data[index] as Map)['NeedCount']
                                                .toString()),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                            (data[index] as Map)['ScanCount']
                                                .toString()),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                      }
                  }
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green)),
              child:
                  Text(widget.nrStatie, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => statieConveer())),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If needed I can provide Information that is missing!